# Edge session.cookie_lifetime

Tags: cookies, microsoft-edge

My website functionality is broken on Edge (Especially login) and I was told it has something to do with the `session.cookie_lifetime`. I would appreciate any help regarding the matter. Please note, I'm not a developer and I do not have any code knowledge.

Some of my php.ini file, if it helps:

```
session.use_cookies = 1
session.cookie_lifetime = 1440
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.cookie_path = 1
session.save_path = "/tmp"
session.auto_start = 1
```

Comment: If you are not a developer and have no code knowledge then why are you tasked with handling your website's functionality? This is something that should be the job of a web developer.

Answer (score 0):

session.cookie_lifetime
This value (default 0, which means until the browser's next restart) defines how long (in seconds) a session cookie will live. This value indirectly defines the "absolute" maximum lifetime of a session, whether the user is active or not. If this value is set to 60, every session ends after an hour.